# how to extract particular data from json list in python

Tags: python, json

I want to extract particular element from json list and I get my result from the code below:

```
result = CF.face.detect(img_url)
```

And when I print result I get:

```
[{u'faceRectangle': {u'width': 246, u'top': 196, u'height': 246, u'left': 113}}, {u'faceRectangle': {u'width': 217, u'top': 213, u'height': 217, u'left': 614}}]
```

Now if i want to get width of first faceRectangle I write:

```
print result['facerectangle']
```

and I recieve

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You should switch to Python version 3.6 while you are still learning. https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 0):

you `result` type is `list` so you need, get first element by index start from 0, and then you will have the `dict` and can get value by key:

```
print type(result)
print type(result[0])

print result[0]['faceRectangle']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the width of the first faceRectangle, you have to get the first element of the list `result[0]`, then the faceRectangle key `result[0]['faceRectangle']` and finally the width key `result[0]['faceRectangle']['width']`.

```
print result[0]['faceRectangle']['width']
```